Mixtral 8x7b, am I running it wrong?
as many companies today we're experiencing running local LLM on our own internal servers. With choosed Mixtral 8x7b as it appeared to be the best value for money for a "french speaking" model. The model itself works pretty well but in terms of performance I have to say i'm quite disapppointed : passed 10 concurrent requests the token generation speed drops significantly making the experience quite unpleasant.
I'm using vllm to run the model on a double NVIDIA H100 PCIe setup, you can see the booting logs below :

INFO 07-01 06:28:12 api_server.py:177] vLLM API server version 0.5.0
INFO 07-01 06:28:12 api_server.py:178] args: Namespace(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, uvicorn_log_level='info', allow_credentials=False, allowed_origins=['*'], allowed_methods=['*'], allowed_headers=['*'], api_key=None, lora_modules=None, chat_template=None, response_role='assistant', ssl_keyfile=None, ssl_certfile=None, ssl_ca_certs=None, ssl_cert_reqs=0, root_path=None, middleware=[], model='mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1', tokenizer=None, skip_tokenizer_init=False, revision=None, code_revision=None, tokenizer_revision=None, tokenizer_mode='auto', trust_remote_code=False, download_dir=None, load_format='safetensors', dtype='auto', kv_cache_dtype='auto', quantization_param_path=None, max_model_len=None, guided_decoding_backend='outlines', distributed_executor_backend=None, worker_use_ray=False, pipeline_parallel_size=1, tensor_parallel_size=2, max_parallel_loading_workers=None, ray_workers_use_nsight=False, block_size=16, enable_prefix_caching=False, disable_sliding_window=False, use_v2_block_manager=False, num_lookahead_slots=0, seed=0, swap_space=4, gpu_memory_utilization=0.9, num_gpu_blocks_override=None, max_num_batched_tokens=None, max_num_seqs=256, max_logprobs=20, disable_log_stats=False, quantization=None, rope_scaling=None, rope_theta=None, enforce_eager=False, max_context_len_to_capture=None, max_seq_len_to_capture=8192, disable_custom_all_reduce=False, tokenizer_pool_size=0, tokenizer_pool_type='ray', tokenizer_pool_extra_config=None, enable_lora=False, max_loras=1, max_lora_rank=16, lora_extra_vocab_size=256, lora_dtype='auto', long_lora_scaling_factors=None, max_cpu_loras=None, fully_sharded_loras=False, device='auto', image_input_type=None, image_token_id=None, image_input_shape=None, image_feature_size=None, image_processor=None, image_processor_revision=None, disable_image_processor=False, scheduler_delay_factor=0.0, enable_chunked_prefill=False, speculative_model=None, num_speculative_tokens=None, speculative_max_model_len=None, speculative_disable_by_batch_size=None, ngram_prompt_lookup_max=None, ngram_prompt_lookup_min=None, model_loader_extra_config=None, preemption_mode=None, served_model_name=None, qlora_adapter_name_or_path=None, engine_use_ray=False, disable_log_requests=False, max_log_len=None)
/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/code-MATOk_fk-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py:1132: FutureWarning: `resume_download` is deprecated and will be removed in version 1.0.0. Downloads always resume when possible. If you want to force a new download, use `force_download=True`.
  warnings.warn(
2024-07-01 06:28:16,256 INFO worker.py:1753 -- Started a local Ray instance.
INFO 07-01 06:28:17 config.py:623] Defaulting to use mp for distributed inference
INFO 07-01 06:28:17 llm_engine.py:161] Initializing an LLM engine (v0.5.0) with config: model='mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1', speculative_config=None, tokenizer='mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1', skip_tokenizer_init=False, tokenizer_mode=auto, revision=None, rope_scaling=None, rope_theta=None, tokenizer_revision=None, trust_remote_code=False, dtype=torch.bfloat16, max_seq_len=32768, download_dir=None, load_format=LoadFormat.SAFETENSORS, tensor_parallel_size=2, disable_custom_all_reduce=False, quantization=None, enforce_eager=False, kv_cache_dtype=auto, quantization_param_path=None, device_config=cuda, decoding_config=DecodingConfig(guided_decoding_backend='outlines'), seed=0, served_model_name=mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1)
(VllmWorkerProcess pid=3627) INFO 07-01 06:28:21 multiproc_worker_utils.py:215] Worker ready; awaiting tasks
INFO 07-01 06:28:21 utils.py:623] Found nccl from library libnccl.so.2
(VllmWorkerProcess pid=3627) INFO 07-01 06:28:21 utils.py:623] Found nccl from library libnccl.so.2
INFO 07-01 06:28:21 pynccl.py:65] vLLM is using nccl==2.20.5
(VllmWorkerProcess pid=3627) INFO 07-01 06:28:21 pynccl.py:65] vLLM is using nccl==2.20.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py", line 239, in main
    cache[rtype].remove(name)
KeyError: '/psm_7a3085ca'
INFO 07-01 06:28:22 custom_all_reduce_utils.py:179] reading GPU P2P access cache from /root/.config/vllm/gpu_p2p_access_cache_for_0,1.json
(VllmWorkerProcess pid=3627) INFO 07-01 06:28:22 custom_all_reduce_utils.py:179] reading GPU P2P access cache from /root/.config/vllm/gpu_p2p_access_cache_for_0,1.json
WARNING 07-01 06:28:22 custom_all_reduce.py:179] Custom allreduce is disabled because your platform lacks GPU P2P capability or P2P test failed. To silence this warning, specify disable_custom_all_reduce=True explicitly.
(VllmWorkerProcess pid=3627) WARNING 07-01 06:28:22 custom_all_reduce.py:179] Custom allreduce is disabled because your platform lacks GPU P2P capability or P2P test failed. To silence this warning, specify disable_custom_all_reduce=True explicitly.
INFO 07-01 06:28:22 weight_utils.py:218] Using model weights format ['*.safetensors']
(VllmWorkerProcess pid=3627) INFO 07-01 06:28:22 weight_utils.py:218] Using model weights format ['*.safetensors']
INFO 07-01 06:29:05 model_runner.py:159] Loading model weights took 43.5064 GB
(VllmWorkerProcess pid=3627) INFO 07-01 06:29:05 model_runner.py:159] Loading model weights took 43.5064 GB
INFO 07-01 06:29:09 distributed_gpu_executor.py:56] # GPU blocks: 23587, # CPU blocks: 4096
INFO 07-01 06:29:12 model_runner.py:878] Capturing the model for CUDA graphs. This may lead to unexpected consequences if the model is not static. To run the model in eager mode, set 'enforce_eager=True' or use '--enforce-eager' in the CLI.
INFO 07-01 06:29:12 model_runner.py:882] CUDA graphs can take additional 1~3 GiB memory per GPU. If you are running out of memory, consider decreasing `gpu_memory_utilization` or enforcing eager mode. You can also reduce the `max_num_seqs` as needed to decrease memory usage.
(VllmWorkerProcess pid=3627) INFO 07-01 06:29:12 model_runner.py:878] Capturing the model for CUDA graphs. This may lead to unexpected consequences if the model is not static. To run the model in eager mode, set 'enforce_eager=True' or use '--enforce-eager' in the CLI.
(VllmWorkerProcess pid=3627) INFO 07-01 06:29:12 model_runner.py:882] CUDA graphs can take additional 1~3 GiB memory per GPU. If you are running out of memory, consider decreasing `gpu_memory_utilization` or enforcing eager mode. You can also reduce the `max_num_seqs` as needed to decrease memory usage.
INFO 07-01 06:29:30 model_runner.py:954] Graph capturing finished in 18 secs.
(VllmWorkerProcess pid=3627) INFO 07-01 06:29:30 model_runner.py:954] Graph capturing finished in 18 secs.
INFO 07-01 06:29:30 serving_chat.py:92] Using default chat template:
INFO 07-01 06:29:30 serving_chat.py:92] {{ bos_token }}{% for message in messages %}{% if (message['role'] == 'user') != (loop.index0 % 2 == 0) %}{{ raise_exception('Conversation roles must alternate user/assistant/user/assistant/...') }}{% endif %}{% if message['role'] == 'user' %}{{ '[INST] ' + message['content'] + ' [/INST]' }}{% elif message['role'] == 'assistant' %}{{ ' ' + message['content'] + eos_token}}{% else %}{{ raise_exception('Only user and assistant roles are supported!') }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}
WARNING 07-01 06:29:30 serving_embedding.py:141] embedding_mode is False. Embedding API will not work.
INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Here is the result of nvidia-smi command, it looks like the model is loaded into GPU memory :
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.90.07              Driver Version: 550.90.07      CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA H100 PCIe               Off |   00000000:00:06.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   33C    P0             81W /  350W |   69810MiB /  81559MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA H100 PCIe               Off |   00000000:00:07.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   34C    P0             79W /  350W |   69712MiB /  81559MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1791      C   ...nvs/code-MATOk_fk-py3.11/bin/python      69792MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      5653      C   ...nvs/code-MATOk_fk-py3.11/bin/python      69694MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Is it normal or is there a problem with my setup ? Does someone have experienced running this model in production and has feedback regarding to the hardware requirements for a given "concurrent request target" ?
EDIT after Jakub's answer
Using the quantized model didn't help although it does run on a single GPU, the throughput is very bad even with a single request.
Moreover adding dtype half or not with the legacy model does not seem to make any difference, I did a few tests with theses options, you can see the results below.
1 request test
command: --model casperhansen/mixtral-instruct-awq --host 0.0.0.0 --quantization awq --load-format safetensors --max-num-seqs 64



chat    | INFO 07-02 09:01:37 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.1%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 09:01:42 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 807.1 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 14.3 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.2%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 09:01:47 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 16.7 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.2%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 09:01:53 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 16.6 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.2%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 09:01:58 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 16.7 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.2%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 09:02:03 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 16.8 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.3%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 09:02:08 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 16.6 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.3%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 09:02:13 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 16.6 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.3%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.

Throughput is really bad, despite only one GPU is used, it is not an option for me.
command: --model mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1 --host 0.0.0.0 --tensor-parallel-size 2 --load-format safetensors --max-num-seqs 64 

chat    | INFO 07-02 08:58:08 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 864.3 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 24.2 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.2%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 08:58:13 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 64.7 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.3%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 08:58:18 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 65.3 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.4%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 08:58:23 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 64.9 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.4%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 08:58:28 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 65.5 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.5%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 08:58:33 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 63.7 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.6%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 08:58:38 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 64.3 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.7%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 08:58:43 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 63.2 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.8%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.


command: --model mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1 --host 0.0.0.0 --tensor-parallel-size 2 --load-format safetensors --max-num-seqs 64 --dtype half

chat    | INFO 07-02 09:23:52 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 812.4 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 0.6 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.1%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 09:23:57 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 64.7 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.2%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 09:24:02 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 65.6 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.3%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 09:24:07 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 64.8 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.3%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 09:24:12 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 64.7 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.4%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
chat    | INFO 07-02 09:24:17 metrics.py:341] Avg prompt throughput: 0.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 64.5 tokens/s, Running: 1 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 1.5%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.

dtype parameter does not impact throughput.
50 requests test
command: --model casperhansen/mixtral-instruct-awq --host 0.0.0.0 --quantization awq --load-format safetensors --max-num-seqs 64


Avg prompt throughput: 3317.6 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 438.7 tokens/s, Running: 49 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 47.8%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
Avg prompt throughput: 3124.9 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 414.4 tokens/s, Running: 50 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 48.2%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
Avg prompt throughput: 1965.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 516.8 tokens/s, Running: 49 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 47.4%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
Avg prompt throughput: 4497.7 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 356.2 tokens/s, Running: 50 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 47.7%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
Avg prompt throughput: 2703.2 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 466.5 tokens/s, Running: 50 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 48.0%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
Avg prompt throughput: 3291.4 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 427.3 tokens/s, Running: 50 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 47.8%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
Avg prompt throughput: 629.7 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 608.9 tokens/s, Running: 50 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 48.5%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.


command: --model mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1 --host 0.0.0.0 --tensor-parallel-size 2 --load-format safetensors --max-num-seqs 64 --dtype half

Avg prompt throughput: 3924.3 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 379.3 tokens/s, Running: 50 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 48.5%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
Avg prompt throughput: 3170.6 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 399.0 tokens/s, Running: 50 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 48.1%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
Avg prompt throughput: 3845.4 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 384.5 tokens/s, Running: 50 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 47.6%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
Avg prompt throughput: 2076.6 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 506.7 tokens/s, Running: 48 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 45.9%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
Avg prompt throughput: 3434.0 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 429.0 tokens/s, Running: 50 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 48.2%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.
Avg prompt throughput: 2494.2 tokens/s, Avg generation throughput: 485.6 tokens/s, Running: 50 reqs, Swapped: 0 reqs, Pending: 0 reqs, GPU KV cache usage: 48.1%, CPU KV cache usage: 0.0%.

Having 50 running requests regardless of dtype parameter make the token throughput quite low, degrading user experience. I guess I expected too much for this setup.

I would recommend trying awq format and not splitting your model on 2 gpus
you would need to download model like this for it to work casperhansen/mixtral-instruct-awq
once you have that make sure to run your model with --quantization awq and --dtype half
dtype might not be necessary for your setup YMMV
also from your logs I couldn't not see if you are using flashattn for backend, install it and see if it might improve your performance
lastly I would try tinkering with parameters such as --max-num-batched-tokens and --max-num-seqs read more here: vllm OpenAI Compatible Server
Another option is to forgo quantization altogether and try use dtype with lower precision, non-quantized models should have highest throughoutput it all depends if you can fit you model on one gpu as that leads to highest tokens/s(in most usecases).

Thanks for your reply, I edited my post accordingly. How can I make sure that vLLM is using flash attention or not ?

I just checked I get similar results to you on A10 where I would expect the performance to be much worse.
flash-attn.
Also try to set --kv-cache-dtype to fp8, this won't work with flash-attn as it currently does not support fp8.
I am afraid I won't be of much more help, try opening an issue or asking on vllm discord you will get more help there :)

Interesting, setting cache type fp8 didn't increase throuhoutput rate but divided by 2 the gpu cache usage. Same performances with A10 card wow, I hope my boss won't read this post... Anyway thanks a lot for your time this was really instructive.
